# Deliver default templates with wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My self written Wordpress plugin includes a custom post type. I want to deploy a default template for this post type. Is it possible to do this inside the plugin's directory? I cannot find any documentation on this.

Having the plugin running "out of the box" seems better to me than telling the user to copy the default template to their theme's directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article has a walkthrough of the functions you'll need to include page templates in your plugin: http://www.unfocus.com/2010/08/10/including-page-templates-from-a-wordpress-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

It should be defined on templates directory as single-xxxx.php

Comment: I know. But it would be great to have it delivered with something like `myplugin-dir/templates/single-xxxx.php`